# Dynamic chart produces a pop-up information/error (check cell reference) message when calculation set to automatic

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dynamic chart that generates a pop-up warning/error message stating there is a cell reference issue.  The message goes away when I change the calculation option from automatic to manual and press F9.  I have tried adding Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual to the beginning of my VBA code but that does not seem to work.  I believe the issue stems from the chart comparing 2 sets of data (initial and follow-up) and there is a null in the initial dataset.

Any ideas on how to eliminate the message so my team does not have to manually change from auto calculation to manual and select F9? (I can send the workbook if needed.)

Comment: First idea would be to edit your question and show us the code you try using. The second one is possible to come only after that... Do you try writing a formula in code?

Comment: Is it possible to send the workbook as I am not sure on 'code' piece.  The formula I am using for the dynamic chart is =OFFSET(CHARTS_DATA!$L$53,0,0,COUNTA(CHARTS_DATA!$L$53:$L$92),1) for the initial  and =OFFSET(CHARTS_DATA!$M$53,0,0,COUNTA(CHARTS_DATA!$M$53:$M$92),1) for the follow-up comparison.  The 'Y' axis formula is =OFFSET(CHARTS_DATA!$K$53,0,0,COUNTA(CHARTS_DATA!$K$53:$K$92),1).

Comment: The code that I am running to generate the chart data is

Comment: I think I figured it out. I had the Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual in the wrong spot.  I have run it a few times and I am not getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. I had the `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` statement in the wrong location. I have run the code a few times now and it is not generating the error.